# Switch in between JList in the JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I'm recently working on a project- Bus Ticket Machine. This is a program which helps the user to print their tickets.

I have one screen (`destPanel`) where I display a list of cities to be chosen (`JList departures`).
 Once the user choses a city the `addListSelectionListener` of the first `JList` will save and return a timetable (`JList timetable`) for the user to choose again and this time save the chosen departure for printing on the ticket later on.

I cannot get the `addListSelectionListener` to stop when the timetable is displayed. This in order to be able to select a departure to be saved for printing the ticket.

---

I've added my three classes showing what I've been working on.

Class one:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;



public class TicketGUI extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TicketGUI();
    }

    private JPanel destPanel    = new JPanel();
    private JPanel departPanel  = new JPanel();
    private JPanel payPanel     = new JPanel();

    private JButton[] buttons;


    // Display size
    private final int WIDTH = 310;
    private final int HEIGHT = 150;

    JList departJList;
    JList defltList;
    Vector<Enum> listContent = new Vector<Enum>();


    //Following line used for adding info to display JList.
    //Vector<Object> listContent = new Vector<Object>();


    JList timeTable; //Not being used.
    private DefaultListModel listModel; //Not being used.
    Vector<String> newListContent = new Vector<String>(); //Not being used.


    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JTextField payField = new JTextField(15);

    public TicketGUI()
    {
        this.setTitle("Bus Ticket Machine");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel agePanel = new JPanel();
        JRadioButton adultButton = new JRadioButton("Adult");
        adultButton.setSelected(true);

        JRadioButton studentButton = new JRadioButton("Student");

        JRadioButton childButton = new JRadioButton("Children");

        //Group the radio buttons.
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(adultButton);
        group.add(studentButton);
        group.add(childButton);


        JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();
        bPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));


        bPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        buttons= new JButton[12];
        for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            buttons[i]=new JButton();
            //buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
        {
            buttons[i-1].setText(""+i);
            bPanel.add(buttons[i-1]);
        }
        buttons[9].setText("X");
        bPanel.add(buttons[9]);
        buttons[10].setText("0");
        bPanel.add(buttons[10]);
        buttons[11].setText("OK");
        bPanel.add(buttons[11]);
        payField.setText("Card Number");
        payField.setEditable(false);

        payPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        payPanel.add(payField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Display
//        listContent.add("London");
//      listContent.add("Bristol");
//      listContent.add("Sheffield");
//      listContent.add("Birmingham");
//      listContent.add("...");


//      listContent.add("Here under list to be displayed after choosing a city");
//      listContent.add("1. London -> Bristol  Depart: 11:45 Arrives: 13:15");
//      listContent.add("2. London -> Bristol  Depart: 12:30 Arrives: 15:00");
//      listContent.add("3. London -> Bristol  Depart: 13:45 Arrives: 16:15");
//      listContent.add("4. London -> Bristol  Depart: 14:30 Arrives: 17:00");
//      listContent.add("...");

//      listContent.add("Your Journey");    
//      listContent.add("Ticket: Adult");
//      listContent.add("From: London ");
//      listContent.add("Going to: Bristol");
//      listContent.add("Leaving: 11:45");
//      listContent.add("Fare: £ 18.00");

        listContent = new Vector<Enum>(Arrays.asList(EnumCity.values()));

        System.out.print(listContent + "one");


//        defltList = new JList(listContent);
//
//        System.out.print(defltList);


        departJList = new JList(listContent);
//      departJList.add(listContent);

        System.out.print("\n\n");
        System.out.print(departJList + "two");

        timeTable = new JList();

        departJList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
            {

                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting())
                {
                    TimeTable selected = new TimeTable();   
                    selected.setTimeTable();
                    newListContent.addAll(selected.getTimeTable());

//                  timeTable.setListData(newListContent.toArray());
//                  departJList.setListData(newListContent);
                }

                System.out.println(newListContent);

//              timeTable.setListData(newListContent.toArray());
                departJList.setListData(newListContent);
//              departJList.setListData(newListContent);    

            }
            });


    JScrollPane m_clScrollpane = new JScrollPane(departJList);
        m_clScrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        JPanel farePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        farePanel.add(adultButton);
        farePanel.add(studentButton);
        farePanel.add(childButton);
        JTextField tf = new JTextField("£ 0.00");
        tf.setEditable(false);
        farePanel.add(tf);
        destPanel.add(farePanel);

        destPanel.add(m_clScrollpane);
        payPanel.add(bPanel);

        add(destPanel);
        add(payPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        setVisible(true);
        pack();

        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() 
        {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                dispose();
                System.exit(0);
        }
        });
    }

}
```

Class two:

```
public enum EnumCity {
    London,
    Bristol,
    Sheffield,
    Birmingham
}
```

Class three:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class TimeTable {

    private String timeTable;

    public TimeTable()
    {
    }   

    public String setTimeTable()
    {   
        return this.timeTable;
    }

    public Vector<String> getTimeTable()
    {
        Vector<String> timeList = new Vector<String>();
        timeList.addElement("1. London -> Bristol  Depart: 11:45 Arrives: 13:15");
        timeList.addElement("2. London -> Bristol  Depart: 12:30 Arrives: 15:00");
        timeList.addElement("3. London -> Bristol  Depart: 13:45 Arrives: 16:15");
        timeList.addElement("4. London -> Bristol  Depart: 14:30 Arrives: 17:00");

        return timeList;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've formatted your posted code some so that the site will show code formatting, but you'll still want to pretty it up including removing empty lines in your imports, and indenting your comments to match your code indentation. Please read the question formatting instructions for more.

Comment: Oh thank you for formatting my code! I was/am going crazy not understanding how it works.

Comment: When you edit your code, click on the question mark to the top and right of the edit box to learn about stackoverflow question formatting secrets. And again, please prettify your code some.

Comment: Thank you David Cain for formatting my code a bit more. I don't dare to do much until I go a "How to edit code in Stackoverflow" course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to stop a listener from working is to remove it. If you are set on swapping the data in your list, you could do:

```
  departJList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {

           // ******* added **********
           ((JList)e.getSource()).removeListSelectionListener(this);

           TimeTable selected = new TimeTable();
           selected.setTimeTable();
           newListContent.addAll(selected.getTimeTable());
        }

        System.out.println(newListContent);
        departJList.setListData(newListContent);

     }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for this one. Removing the Listener works for me so far. I still have more questions about the same program I'm working on but I'll have to take it in another quest I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the data in the list (which is a good idea generally), you could establish two different lists, one that manages list of cities and one that managers the list of time tables.

Then using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), you could switch between them.

This means that you don't need to worry about switching selection listeners each time you switch the data.

Comment: It says that I can choose the showing card :  By asking for either the first or last card, in the order it was added to the container.
By flipping through the deck backwards or forwards
By specifying a card with a specific name. And this last means that I have to make a card for every city. It sounds complicated if it is that the programs is going to be updated regularly by maybe adding new cities to the display and to the timetable...

Comment: No, I'd create two cards.  One for the list of destinations and one for the list of time tables.  Then I'd just switch the models of those lists.  What it means is, you can define actions for the two lists and based which is only different based on the information they hold.  This means you don't need to mess around with listener states and other flags

Comment: I'm taking a break studying more about card layout which I think it might be something I can use in this program. Thanks for your help and giving me more ideas about how java works.